# Angular $location.path() and URL parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, path, location

I'm struggling with Angular $location service... I am trying to redirect a user to this URL : **"/test/0/0"**, and my route.js is configured with :

```
$routeProvider
.when ('/test/:param1/:param2',{
    // Behavior here
})
```

When I simply do

```
$location.path('/test/0/0');
```

Angular seems not understand this path and can't associate it with the one I configured in the routes.

I have read about the $location service : I have tried $location.search(), .url(), but none of them works.

Any ideas would be welcome!

Comment: Can you please jsfiddle or plunker your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could put a template and a controller to these route

```
.when('/page/:param1/:param2',{
    templateUrl:'page.html',
    controller: 'PageController'
})
```

[I made an example to show you it running, you can check the code here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/OnU91zepNkmdyUWwmQkS?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to thank you NEOLPAR for this piece of code which depicts accuratly what my problem was and seems to solve it perfectly. I tried to do what you suggest and unhopefuly it didn't work. But thanks a lot anyway!

As I was all out of ideas, I tried to replace $location.path() by a window.location.href directly, which also didn't work. This lead me to the conclusion that Angular just didn't bother reloading the page (because I didn't precise it but going to '/test/0/0' was just going to the current page). Thus I googled how to force a page reload and found a really nice solution (for my precise situation), which is to use :

```
$route.reload();
```

Thank you one more time for your help!